# Alguna idea de porque eclipse no me reconoce mi user y password para hacer un push desde eclipse?

Tags: java, git, eclipse, push

Por más que introduzco correctamente mis credenciales me sale de nuevo la ventana y no me deja avanzar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se el caso de github, pero tal vez necesitas crear un token para usar de password en vez de la password. Otra opción es conectarte por ssh y no necesitarás user y psw (solo la clave privada). Fijate en Internet lo del token, seguro sale algo

Comment: Tal cual!!!Cree un nuevo token ya que el otro lo tenía caducado y ya me pusheo el repo. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dijo el compañero tuve que crear un nuevo token y ponerlo en la password en vez de mi password para acceder a github, el usuario es el mismo con el que accedo, en mi caso era porque tenía el token caducado